# How to get the position of elements in a list?

Tags: r, list

Given a list variable, I'd like to have a data frame of the positions of each element.  For a simple non-nested list, it seems quite straightforward.

For example, here's a list of character vectors.

```
l <- replicate(
  10,
  sample(letters, rpois(1, 2), replace = TRUE),
  simplify = FALSE
)
```

`l` looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "m"

[[2]]
[1] "o" "r"

[[3]]
[1] "g" "m"
# etc.
```

To get the data frame of positions, I can use:

```
d <- data.frame(
  value = unlist(l),
  i = rep(seq_len(length(l)), lengths(l)),
  j = rapply(l, seq_along, how = "unlist"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
head(d)
##   value i j
## 1     m 1 1
## 2     o 2 1
## 3     r 2 2
## 4     g 3 1
## 5     m 3 2
## 6     w 4 1
```

Given a trickier nested list, for example:

```
l2 <- list(
  "a",
  list("b", list("c", c("d", "a", "e"))),
  character(),
  c("e", "b"),
  list("e"),
  list(list(list("f")))
)
```

this doesn't easily generalize.

The output I expect for this example is:

```
data.frame(
  value = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "e", "e", "b", "e", "f"), 
  i1 = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6), 
  i2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1), 
  i3 = c(NA, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, 1, 1), 
  i4 = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA, 1), 
  i5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1)
)
```

How do I get a data frame of positions for a nested list?

Comment: Are you expecting a data.frame with 6 columns (value + 5 levels of nesting) as result for `l2`?

Comment: This seems to be essentially a combination of `melt(l2)` + `rapply(l2, seq_along)`. The question is how to easily combine those two :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, that's incredibly simple - you have my upvote if you post as answer

Comment: @docendodiscimus, posted an answer. It's (obviously) not as fast as your approach.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's an approach that yields a slightly different output than you showed, but it'll be useful further down the road.

```
f <- function(l) {
  names(l) <- seq_along(l)
  lapply(l, function(x) {
    x <- setNames(x, seq_along(x))
    if(is.list(x)) f(x) else x
  })
}
```

Function `f` simply iterates (recursively) through all levels of the given list and names it's elements `1,2,...,n` where `n` is the length of the (sub)list. Then, we can make use of the fact that `unlist` has a `use.names` argument that is `TRUE` by default and has effect when used on a named list (that's why we have to use `f` to name the list first).

For the nested list `l2` it returns:

```
unlist(f(l2))
#      1.1     2.1.1   2.2.1.1   2.2.2.1   2.2.2.2   2.2.2.3       4.1       4.2     5.1.1 6.1.1.1.1 
#      "a"       "b"       "c"       "d"       "a"       "e"       "e"       "b"       "e"       "f"
```

Now, in order to return a `data.frame` as asked for in the question, I'd do this:

```
g <- function(l) {
  vec <- unlist(f(l))
  n <- max(lengths(strsplit(names(vec), ".", fixed=TRUE)))
  require(tidyr)
  data.frame(
    value = unname(vec),
    i = names(vec)
  ) %>% 
    separate(i, paste0("i", 1:n), sep = "\\.", fill = "right", convert = TRUE)
}
```

And apply it like this:

```
g(l2)
#   value i1 i2 i3 i4 i5
#1      a  1  1 NA NA NA
#2      b  2  1  1 NA NA
#3      c  2  2  1  1 NA
#4      d  2  2  2  1 NA
#5      a  2  2  2  2 NA
#6      e  2  2  2  3 NA
#7      e  4  1 NA NA NA
#8      b  4  2 NA NA NA
#9      e  5  1  1 NA NA
#10     f  6  1  1  1  1
```

An improved version of `g`, contributed by @AnandaMahto (thanks!), would use `data.table`:

```
g <- function(inlist) {
    require(data.table)
    temp <- unlist(f(inlist))
    setDT(tstrsplit(names(temp), ".", fixed = TRUE))[, value := unname(temp)][]
}
```

---

**Edit** (credits go to @TylerRinkler - thanks!)

This has the beneft of easily being converted to a **data.tree** object which can then be converted to many other data types.  With a slight mod to `g`:

```
g <- function(l) {
  vec <- unlist(f(l))
  n <- max(lengths(strsplit(names(vec), ".", fixed=TRUE)))
  require(tidyr)
  data.frame(
    i = names(vec),
    value = unname(vec)
  ) %>% 
    separate(i, paste0("i", 1:n), sep = "\\.", fill = "right", convert = TRUE)
}

library(data.tree)

x <- data.frame(top=".", g(l2))
x$pathString <- apply(x, 1, function(x) paste(trimws(na.omit(x)), collapse="/"))
mytree <- data.tree::as.Node(x)

mytree
#                   levelName
#1  .                        
#2   ¦--1                    
#3   ¦   °--1                
#4   ¦       °--a            
#5   ¦--2                    
#6   ¦   ¦--1                
#7   ¦   ¦   °--1            
#8   ¦   ¦       °--b        
#9   ¦   °--2                
#10  ¦       ¦--1            
#11  ¦       ¦   °--1        
#12  ¦       ¦       °--c    
#13  ¦       °--2            
#14  ¦           ¦--1        
#15  ¦           ¦   °--d    
#16  ¦           ¦--2        
#17  ¦           ¦   °--a    
#18  ¦           °--3        
#19  ¦               °--e    
#20  ¦--4                    
#21  ¦   ¦--1                
#22  ¦   ¦   °--e            
#23  ¦   °--2                
#24  ¦       °--b            
#25  ¦--5                    
#26  ¦   °--1                
#27  ¦       °--1            
#28  ¦           °--e        
#29  °--6                    
#30      °--1                
#31          °--1            
#32              °--1        
#33                  °--1    
#34                      °--f
```

And to produce a nice plot:

```
plot(mytree)
```

[image: pic]

Other forms of presenting the data:

```
as.list(mytree)
ToDataFrameTypeCol(mytree)
```

More on converting **data.tree** types:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html#tree-conversion
http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-convert-an-r-data-tree-to-json/

Comment: Great stuff.  I was sloppy about specifying the expected output, but setting `i = names(vec)` and then calling `tidyr::separate` gets me what I want.

Comment: @docendo discimus I made an addition (great answer by the way) feel free to roll back if it doesn't fit with what you intended. +1

Comment: @TylerRinker, thanks for your edit, that's actually quite cool! I might add that graph too

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative. It's not going to be as fast as the approach by @docendodiscimus, but it is still pretty straightforward.

The basic idea is to use `melt` from "reshape2"/"data.table". `melt` has a `method` for `list`s that creates output like the following:

```
melt(l2)
#    value L3 L2 L4 L1
# 1      a NA NA NA  1
# 2      b NA  1 NA  2
# 3      c  1  2 NA  2
# 4      d  2  2 NA  2
# 5      a  2  2 NA  2
# 6      e  2  2 NA  2
# 7      e NA NA NA  4
# 8      b NA NA NA  4
# 9      e NA  1 NA  5
# 10     f  1  1  1  6
```

Except for the column ordering and the last value that you're interested in, that seems to have all the info you're after. To get the last value you're interested in, you can use `rapply(l2, seq_along)`.

Putting those two requirements together, you would have something like this:

```
myFun <- function(inlist) {
  require(reshape2)                           ## Load required package
  x1 <- melt(inlist)                          ## Melt the data
  x1[[paste0("L", ncol(x1))]] <- NA_integer_  ## Add a column to hold the position info
  x1 <- x1[c(1, order(names(x1)[-1]) + 1)]    ## Reorder the columns
  vals <- rapply(inlist, seq_along)           ## These are the positional values
  positions <- max.col(is.na(x1), "first")    ## This is where the positions should go
  x1[cbind(1:nrow(x1), positions)] <- vals    ## Matrix indexing for replacement
  x1                                          ## Return the output
}

myFun(l2)
#    value L1 L2 L3 L4 L5
# 1      a  1  1 NA NA NA
# 2      b  2  1  1 NA NA
# 3      c  2  2  1  1 NA
# 4      d  2  2  2  1 NA
# 5      a  2  2  2  2 NA
# 6      e  2  2  2  3 NA
# 7      e  4  1 NA NA NA
# 8      b  4  2 NA NA NA
# 9      e  5  1  1 NA NA
# 10     f  6  1  1  1  1
```

---

The "data.table" version of `g` from the answer by @docendodiscimus is a little bit more direct:

```
g <- function(inlist) {
  require(data.table)
  temp <- unlist(f(inlist))
  setDT(tstrsplit(names(temp), ".", fixed = TRUE))[, value := unname(temp)][]
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. Acutally I'm a bit surprised you're saying that my answer would be faster. But in any case, it's a very good approach

Comment: @docendodiscimus, it's essentially `unlist` and string splitting with some fun recursion, right? :-)

Comment: I like your data.table version of g, especially since it avoids doing the split twice. Mind if I add a reference about that in my answer?

Comment: @docendodiscimus, no problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to docendo's, but attempting to operate as much as possible inside the recursion than fixing the result afterwards:

```
ff = function(x)
{
    if(!is.list(x)) if(length(x)) return(seq_along(x)) else return(NA)
    lapply(seq_along(x), 
           function(i) cbind(i, do.call(rBind, as.list(ff(x[[i]])))))
}

ans = do.call(rBind, ff(l2))
data.frame(value = unlist(l2), 
           ans[rowSums(is.na(ans[, -1L])) != (ncol(ans) - 1L), ])
#   value X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1      a  1  1 NA NA NA
#2      b  2  1  1 NA NA
#3      c  2  2  1  1 NA
#4      d  2  2  2  1 NA
#5      a  2  2  2  2 NA
#6      e  2  2  2  3 NA
#7      e  4  1 NA NA NA
#8      b  4  2 NA NA NA
#9      e  5  1  1 NA NA
#10     f  6  1  1  1  1
```

`rBind` is a wrapper around `rbind` to avoid the "non-matching columns" errors:

```
rBind = function(...) 
{
    args = lapply(list(...), function(x) if(is.matrix(x)) x else matrix(x))
    nc = max(sapply(args, ncol))
    do.call(rbind, 
            lapply(args, function(x) 
                           do.call(cbind, c(list(x), rep_len(list(NA), nc - ncol(x))))))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with `rrapply` in the `rrapply`-package (extended version of base `rapply`) using `how = "melt"` to return a melted data.frame similar to `reshape2::melt`:

```r
library(rrapply)

## use rapply or rrapply to convert terminal nodes to lists
l2_list <- rapply(l2, f = as.list, how = "replace")

## use rrapply with how = "melt" to return melted data.frame
l2_melt <- rrapply(l2_list, how = "melt")
#>     L1  L2   L3   L4   L5 value
#> 1  ..1 ..1 <NA> <NA> <NA>     a
#> 2  ..2 ..1  ..1 <NA> <NA>     b
#> 3  ..2 ..2  ..1  ..1 <NA>     c
#> 4  ..2 ..2  ..2  ..1 <NA>     d
#> 5  ..2 ..2  ..2  ..2 <NA>     a
#> 6  ..2 ..2  ..2  ..3 <NA>     e
#> 7  ..4 ..1 <NA> <NA> <NA>     e
#> 8  ..4 ..2 <NA> <NA> <NA>     b
#> 9  ..5 ..1  ..1 <NA> <NA>     e
#> 10 ..6 ..1  ..1  ..1  ..1     f
```

NB: we can convert the level columns to numeric columns afterwards if necessary.

```r
rrapply(l2_melt, condition = function(x, .xname) grepl("^L", .xname), f = function(x) as.numeric(sub("\\.+", "", x)))
#>    L1 L2 L3 L4 L5 value
#> 1   1  1 NA NA NA     a
#> 2   2  1  1 NA NA     b
#> 3   2  2  1  1 NA     c
#> 4   2  2  2  1 NA     d
#> 5   2  2  2  2 NA     a
#> 6   2  2  2  3 NA     e
#> 7   4  1 NA NA NA     e
#> 8   4  2 NA NA NA     b
#> 9   5  1  1 NA NA     e
#> 10  6  1  1  1  1     f
```

---

**Computation times**

Using `rrapply` instead of `reshape2::melt` can give significant speed-ups for (very) large nested lists as shown in the benchmark timings below:

```r
## create deeply nested list
deep_list <- rrapply(list(1, 1), classes = c("list", "numeric"), condition = function(x, .xpos) length(.xpos) < 18, f = function(x) list(1, 1), how = "recurse")

system.time(reshape2::melt(deep_list))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#> 119.747   0.024 119.784
system.time(rrapply(deep_list, how = "melt"))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.240   0.008   0.249

## create large shallow nested list
large_list <- lapply(replicate(500, 1, simplify = F), function(x) replicate(500, 1, simplify = F))

system.time(reshape2::melt(large_list))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  40.558   0.008  40.569
system.time(rrapply(large_list, how = "melt"))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   0.073   0.000   0.073
```